# Interpretation of $\mu \cdot \sigma$

Tags: statistics, variance, means

I just read about the [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation)

$$\frac{\sigma}{\mu}$$

and the [signal-to-noise ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio)

$$\frac{\mu}{\sigma}$$

and asked myself how to interpret the product of mean and variance:

$$\mu \cdot \sigma$$

Is there an intuitive explanation of this quantity?

Comment: The coefficient of variation comes up because sometimes relative error is more important than absolute error. A scale with a $\pm1$ kg variance will accurately weigh a $1000$ kg item, but not a 3 kg item, For similar reasons, signal-to-noise is also something important that comes up. But in both cases, nobody said "I wonder if dividing these two values would produce something useful". Instead, they were led to these ratios by the problem at hand. If you ever find a problem needing the product, then you will know what the significance is. But don't hold your breath.